# How to serialize anchor instruction from non-anchor contract

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I am trying to invoke Anchor-contract from a regular solana contract and i am keep getting the error

```
 Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionMissing. Error Number: 100. Error Message: 8 byte instruction identifier not provided.
```

This is my instruction

```
#[derive(Debug, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, PartialEq)]
pub enum ConfigInstruction {
    Initialize,
}

pub fn initialize(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    config: &Pubkey,
    authority: &Pubkey,
) -> Instruction {
    let accounts = vec![
        AccountMeta::new(*config, true),
        AccountMeta::new(*authority, true),
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(system_program::id(), false),
    ];

    Instruction::new_with_borsh(
        *program_id,
        &ConfigInstruction::Initialize,
        accounts,
    )
}
```

Seems like anchor is waiting a 8-byte long encoded instruction. While borsh serializes it to a vector with size 1. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Really took some time to sort this out. Posting so this might be helpful for someone else.

So in order to use anchor's instruction for non-anchor contract you need to import InstructionData trait

```
use anchor_lang::InstructionData;
```

You instructions will be available using

```
use your_anchor_program::instruction::CamelCaseInstructionName
```

Create instruction as usual

```
 Instruction {
        program_id: *program_id,
        accounts: vec![
            ...
        ],
        data: CamelCaseInstructionName.data(),
    }
```